# How can I prevent users interacting with objects behind a frontmost custom view?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

[image]

I have the custom view 'Login Details Popup View'. It is the frontmost object. However, even though the user can't see elements behind the view when the program is running, you can still interact with them. For example, if the cursor is placed where I have drawn the X (not the white exit cross but the black one I have drawn on), the cursor switches to the typing\text entry cursor because it is hovering over the black text view underneath even though it can't be seen.

How can I stop this from happening?

EDIT - Not a duplicate, other question is in objective-c not swift, features no relevance to xcode and doesn't have an answer that works...

Comment: Doesn't have an answer that works & is in a different language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a full screen view and add Login Details Popup View in centre of that view. As the view is full screen interaction with background textview will not work. With this. added Textview is not accessible in any scenario but make sure imageview should be equal to the main view

[image]

Comment: So add another custom view that is larger than the view controller? And then position that one place behind the login details popup view?

Comment: Yup exactly.. but custom view will contain the login view too..
Also can you share the position you set for Login view??

Comment: Just tried this, it didn't have any effect. Just to check I'm on the same page as you: I added a custom view to the storyboard and made it larger than the view controller, 1920x1080, then I centered it and placed the login popup inside it. If that's what you meant then it didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: When you say make a full screen view, is there some attribute to simply tick 'full screen'?

Comment: The original view controller isn't full screen by the way, its 1000ish by 700ish

Comment: So you can still access the black text view??

Comment: yeah, unfortunately so

Comment: As workaround you can added full-size image view and after that add the login popup but for that you need to manage hide-show of both image view and login-popup

Comment: Yeah that doesn't change anything either. None of the extra views stop me from accessing the view controller UI underneath

Comment: Actually, they stop me from using the UI, but the cursor still changes when I hover over the text fields, it's so annoying

Comment: @Cutter Imageview with editable true helped me to restrict  the access of background

Comment: Yeah none of this is stopping the cursor changing when I hover over the black text view from within the login popup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197348/discussion-between-jay-and-cutter).

Comment: This did eventually half solve my problem. It prevents interaction with elements behind the pop up but the cursor still changes to a text selector.